# Access HttpContext.Current.Session data fail sometimes on class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, class-library

I've a class library and a mvc project on the same solution. Sometimes I've access the session data when need validate rules for user access, but another times the return is "null". In my searches on internet I could not find a workable solution for this case. This problem occurs when I use a simple form to searches on a table data.
You have any sugestion? 
Thanks for now.
(Bellow my code fragment)

```
public class EasyLabSimpleRoleProvider: RoleProvider
{
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> empresa;
        empresa = HttpContext.Current.Session["Empresa"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
        //when I use a search form, HttpContext... return null.
        //....
    }

    //....
}
```

Comment: Is it when you call it "some times" or "from some places"? Take a look at the [request lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx "HttpApplication Class") to check if you're calling it before the session state is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem (specifically) when corrected my form, using the same javascript functions (generics) applicable to other forms in my project. I don't know the reason for the web form not work without these definitions and the session also not work consequently.

This is my solution:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", @controller, FormMethod.Get, new { @id = "frmFiltro", data_tiposub = "2", @class = "", role = "form" }))
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try inheriting from IReadOnlySessionState too. It works when you create custom handlers, maybe could help you there too.

```
public class EasyLabSimpleRoleProvider: RoleProvider, IReadOnlySessionState 
{

    //....
}
```

Comment: Thaks @Javi. I will test this. For now found another solution that met me, not very elegant, but solves the moment. Share soon.

Comment: @Javi, isn't `IReadOnlySessionState` used only with HTTP handlers? [See the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate.aspx "IReadOnlySessionState Interface").

Comment: @Paulo Morgado yes, documentation says you should use it in your HTTP handler, but as is just a marker interface there is no issue to use it anywhere you want. It sometimes helps when you work on MVC projects with custom classes accessing the session. There is no prohibition or note saying it cannot be used in other places anyway.

Comment: @Javi, whidh custom classes would those be?